# Direct sum of submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

> Let $\left\{ M_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ be a family of submodules of
>   $R$-module $M$. Prove that $M$ is direct sum of $\left\{ M_{i}\right\}
>  _{i\in I}$ i.e $M=\oplus M_{i}$ iff for all $m\in M$, $m$ is written uniquely with the form $m=\sum_{finite}m_{i},m_{i}\in M_{i}$

Help me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your definition of direct sum?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules

Comment: $\oplus_{i\in I}M_{i}=\left\langle \cup_{t\in I}i_{t}\left(M_{t}\right)\right\rangle $ with $i_{t}$ is projection form module $M_{t}$ to $\oplus_{i\in I}M_{i}$

Comment: Projections goes another way around u have injections and your definition lacks universal property.